# Syntax specification for hint directives

Tags: delphi, syntax

Everyone knows about hint directives. However from reviewing various modules, i learned what, for example, `deprecated` accepts string -literal- to be emitted in the same manner `$MESSAGE` does:

```
procedure StinkStr(S: string); deprecated 'You are unemployed now.';
```

However, documentation being modestly silent about that (highest version i have my hands on is D2010) and i hate guesswork in exact sciences - the questions are:

- where this syntax is documented?
- and, since which version it has been available?

Correction: accepts string literals only, refuses constants (a la `external`).

---

Current findings: D210 chokes on string literals accompanying any hint directive other than deprecated, also eats the hint if unit is marked with it.

Comment: You can use such strings at least in Delphi 2009.

Comment: The portability directives (`platform`, `deprecated` and `library`) were introduced in Delphi 6 / Kylix 1. In fact it was Kylix that prompted their addition. In Delphi 6 the string message syntax you describe is not available. I can't find any documentation of that syntax in the D2010 help either. That's all I know!

Comment: It *should* be mentioned here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Hinting_Directives See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280462/lesser-known-language-constructs-of-object-pascal-delphi/280465#280465

Comment: `experimental` directive joined hint family later

Comment: It does seem like it was introduced in 2009: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/6hidden_delphi2009.html

Comment: I can confirm it's not available in D2007, so it's D2009 as Andreas says.

Comment: experimental definitely not available in Delphi7. Deprecated is (and we use it). Deprecated with a string gives [Error] ProcessResultsFrm.pas(405): ';' expected but string constant found (yes, I'm still using Delphi 7)

Comment: the 3 I mentioned are in the d6 what's new. D6 was the CLX release.

Comment: The `deprecated` keyword itself was introduced in D6. Support for its optional string parameter was introduced in D2009.

Comment: Too bad @Worm Regards cannot accept the set of comments as the correct answer...

Answer (score 4):

It's documented here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deprecated

As the comments mention above, it seems to have been introduced in Delphi 2009. Another reference is http://www.tindex.net/Language/deprecatedwithcomment.html

Comment: Did you notice C++ category in the first link?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't. Sorry about that, that should be bigger for old eyes like mine :-)